# Does Alf work in the Infinite Library?

Tags: nanoha

Throughout Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha StrikerS we see small appearances of Fate's Familiar Alf. The only time she seems to have an impact in the story is near the end, when she is with Yuuno in the Infinite Library helping him research Saints Cradle.

In one of the Flashbacks when Nanoha is saying how she would be happy if Vivio was happy, while being reminded that Vivio won't be happy anywhere else without her Mamas, Alf is shown playing with Vivio.

I am wondering if Alf actually has a job working in the Infinite Library to replace the last two Familiars who worked there or if she was only just helping Yuuno that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two familiars that you mentioned, Aria Liese and Lotte Liese, were helping at the explicit request of Yuuno. They did not work in the Infinite Library at any given time, other than that moment. Due to Yuuno's extreme effectiveness at organizing documents in a pile of organized junk, he was invited to become the head librarian.

Arf was no working at TSAB during the StrikerS period, as mentioned in the sound stages. According to that, she primarily spends time at Earth babysitting. I do not know of a reference that links her to the Infinite Library, other than appearing once in StrikerS. She might have been there to visit for all we know, but it might be something part-time as well.

Comment: i had a feeling the sound stages had the snwer but i can't understand Japanese and can't find text translations to read while i listen

Comment: Translations can be found quite easily, actually. Google for "Nanoha Sound Stage Translation" and several results will appear. One of them on the AnimeSuki forum, and others sharing translations+sound stages through file sharing.